# Is there any way in DB2 to find temp table from the session?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

Is there any way in DB2 to find temp table from the session ?

I have created a temp table pertaining to session

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP_TABLE_NAME
(   
        COL_1 VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
        COL_2 VARCHAR(10)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

When I am trying to create query

```
select * from sysibm.systables where owner='SESSION' and name='TEMP_TABLE_NAME'
```

yields 0 rows.

Am I looking at the incorrect table to find temp tables ?

Thanks !

Comment: I suspect this is the case of an X-Y problem. If you want to access the temp table in the same session that created it, you already know it exists and its name. If you are in a different session, you won't be able to access another session's temp table. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

A  declared global temporary table ( DGTT)  will not appear in the catalog, this is the design - so you will not find a DGTT in sysibm.systables.  A DGTT cannot be used by any other program except the one that declares it - it is specific to that session, hence there's no value to having it in the catalogue.

If you are using Db2 for z/OS (v10 or higher),  or Db2-LUW, you may need instead, a "CREATED global temporary table" (CGTT)  which uses a different syntax `create global temporary table ...`  These *are* catalogued, but you need relevant permissions to create them.

See the [Db2-LUW documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053719.html).
or for Db2 for z/OS [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createglobaltemptable.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [SYSIBMADM.ADMINTEMPTABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0054906.html) administrative view.
If you want to see all the DGTTs created in your session, then:

```
SELECT TABNAME
FROM SYSIBMADM.ADMINTEMPTABLES
WHERE TEMPTABTYPE='D'
AND APPLICATION_HANDLE=mon_get_application_handle();
```

Comment: I think this does not work for DB2 for z/OS , I am seeing  Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SYSIBMADM.ADMINTEMPTABLES, DRIVER=3.63.75

Comment: `SYSIBMADM.ADMINTEMPTABLES` doesn't exist in DB2 for Z/OS. So, this answer is not applicable to your case. I've added the corresponding tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs !